# How to create a submatrix of a randomly filled matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with 5 rows and 3 columns. I filled the matrix with random numbers 0 -10 by using randi([0 10]). I want to create a submatrix by subtracting the last 3 rows of the original matrix. How can i go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show  us example inputs and expected outputs? It's not clear what you want. Do you mean: `X(1:end-2,:)`?

Comment: Posting your code here can be helpful

Comment: Yes I have matrix called matrix. I filled it like matrix = [randi([0 10])  randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]); .....]. From that I created a 5 x 3 matrix with random numbers between 0 and 10. Now I want to be able to create a submatrix that is the same but without the last 3 rows. But I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: @Suever That helps I just figured it out. Thank you so much!